How to prevent two functions from deleting boxes and lines in second script
I combined an open source tradingview indicator for LuxAlgo (Order blocks & breaker blocks [LuxAlgo]) with a private indicator of mine.
The problem here is the last for loop which I show you here in the picture. It's from LuxAlgo indicator which it delete all the old boxes and lines areas generated before the indicator re-generate another fresh boxes and lines each one minute using the next codes after this for loop.
The two functions 'box.all' & 'line.all' also delete all the boxes and lines in my private script indicator.
What should I do to limit those two functions job only for LuxAlgo script? You can see the open source of LuxAlgo indicator here in link:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/piIbWMpY-Order-Blocks-Breaker-Blocks-LuxAlgo/
How should I replace 'box.all', 'line.all'? or how to separate between two indicators functions in the same script?

Create an array for each of items created by the lux algo indicator (box and line). When a new box or line is created push those into the array you created and then finally instead of using box.all and line.all use the arrays you created. For example using the boxes
var boxes = array.new<box>()

method display(ob id, css, break_css)=>
    if id.breaker
        boxes.push(box.new(id.loc, id.top, id.break_loc, id.btm, css.notransp()
          , bgcolor = css
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time))

        boxes.push(box.new(id.break_loc, id.top, time+1, id.btm, na
          , bgcolor = break_css
          , extend = extend.right
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time))
        
        line.new(id.loc, id.top, id.break_loc, id.top, xloc.bar_time, color = css.notransp())
        line.new(id.loc, id.btm, id.break_loc, id.btm, xloc.bar_time, color = css.notransp())
        line.new(id.break_loc, id.top, time+1, id.top, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, break_css.notransp(), line.style_dashed)
        line.new(id.break_loc, id.btm, time+1, id.btm, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, break_css.notransp(), line.style_dashed)
    else
        boxes.push(box.new(id.loc, id.top, time, id.btm, na
          , bgcolor = css
          , extend = extend.right
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time))
        
        line.new(id.loc, id.top, time, id.top, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, css.notransp())
        line.new(id.loc, id.btm, time, id.btm, xloc.bar_time, extend.right, css.notransp())

for bx in boxes
    bx.delete()

